# Strange Images issue with Gulp.js

Tags: gulp

I'm having a strange issue with gulp and my images directory. I have a range of images in `src/img`, but after I run gulp, every single image in the output folder `dist/img` is an exact copy of the last image in the source directory, but with the correct filenames.

This was working fine before, it's just gone barmy recently for no apparent reason.

Here is my gulpfile.js, adapted from [this blog post](http://markgoodyear.com/2014/01/getting-started-with-gulp/):

```
// Load plugins
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    clean = require('gulp-clean'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    cache = require('gulp-cache'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    lr = require('tiny-lr'),
    server = lr();

// Styles
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/css/main.sass')
    .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded', }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(livereload(server))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }));
});

// .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
// .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))

// Scripts
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/js/**/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(livereload(server))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Scripts task complete' }));
});

// Images
gulp.task('images', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/img/**/*')
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 3, progressive: true, interlaced: true })))
    .pipe(livereload(server))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Images task complete' }));
});

// Clean
gulp.task('clean', function() {
  return gulp.src(['dist'], {read: false})
    .pipe(clean());
});

// Default task
gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function() {
    gulp.run('styles', 'scripts', 'images');
});

// Watch
gulp.task('watch', function() {

  // Listen on port 35729
  server.listen(35729, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err)
    };

    // Watch .sass files
    gulp.watch('src/css/**/*.sass', function(event) {
      console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
      gulp.run('styles');
    });

    // Watch .js files
    gulp.watch('src/js/**/*.js', function(event) {
      console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
      gulp.run('scripts');
    });

    // Watch image files
    gulp.watch('src/img/**/*', function(event) {
      console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
      gulp.run('images');
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: My guess is that it's the `gulp-cache` plugin.  Remove that from the images task.

Comment: @OverZealous yep, that's it. Can you please post that as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My guess is that it's the `gulp-cache` plugin. Remove that from the images task.

A better alternative to the cache plugin (which, in my opinion, has too much "magic") is the [`gulp-newer`](https://npmjs.org/package/gulp-newer) plugin, which simple filters the file list based on the last-modified date of the files.  It's much simpler, and less magical.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `gulp-newer`, I'll switch to that.

Comment: Had a different issue with `gulp-cache` working on my original server but not a newly cloned instance. Switched to `gulp-newer` and no more issues.